# How map an exception from a Mono to another exception

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have an endpoint in Spring Webflux (Java 20) that receives a UUID string and I need to validate it using UUID.fromString. If the latter throws an exception because the String is malformed, how can catch and rethrow the exception?

This is the simplest code snippet that shows the problem, where I try to catch the IllegalArgumentException and propagate it as an `AssertionError instead.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono.just(UUID.fromString("123"))
            .doOnError(IllegalArgumentException.class, e -> Mono.error(new AssertionError("")))
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

```
Mono.just(UUID.fromString("123"))
    .onErrorMap(IllegalArgumentException.class, e -> new AssertionError(""))
    .subscribe();
```

```
Mono.just(UUID.fromString("123"))
    .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new AssertionError("hello")))
    .subscribe();
```

Whatever I try, the result is always that the IllegalArgumentException is not caught and just bubbles up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 123
    at java.base/java.util.UUID.fromString1(UUID.java:280)
    at java.base/java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:258)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Operators in Spring Webflux are designed to handle errors that occur during the reactive stream processing, such as errors emitted by upstream publishers or operators. **They do not catch exceptions that occur during the initial creation of the `UUID` using `UUID.fromString`**.

But, you can deal with it using a simple try-catch block:

```java
try {
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("123");
    Mono.just(uuid).subscribe();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    throw new AssertionError("Invalid UUID string", e);
}
```